# Flask-SQLAlchemy | UnmappedInstanceError: Class '...' is mapped, but this instance lacks instrumentation

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm making a web-app using Flask-SQLAlchemy. I have a route that constantly gives the error shown in the title. Here's a breakdown of what I'm doing:

1. This route:

```
@bp.route('/edit_nutrition', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_nutrition():
    # ...
    current_user.set_nutri_info()
    db.session.commit()
    # ...
```

2. calls this function:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    # ...
    info = db.relationship('NutritionInfo', uselist=False,
                           cascade="all, delete-orphan", passive_deletes=True)
    # ...
    def set_nutri_info(self):
        if self.info is None:
            self.info = NutritionInfo()
        # ...(gets a dictionary called indiv_goals)...
        for key, value in indiv_goals.items():
            setattr(self.info, key, value)
```

3. Which creates the .info used in this route:

```
@bp.route('/nutrition_goals', methods=['GET'])
def nutrition_goals():
    # ...
    goals=current_user.info.get_data(display=True)
```

4. Which is calling this function:

```
class NutritionInfo(db.Model):
    # ...
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    # ...
    def get_data(self, display=False):
        if self.user_id is None: # <-- here's where the error happens
            # ...
```

Here's the traceback:

```
File "/home/cgf/Documents/code/github/nutritrack/app/main/routes.py", line 180, in nutrition_goals
goals=current_user.info.get_data(display=True)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/home/cgf/Documents/code/github/nutritrack/app/models.py", line 194, in get_data
if self.user_id is None:
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/home/cgf/miniconda3/envs/nutritrack/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 477, in __get__
util.raise_(
^

File "/home/cgf/miniconda3/envs/nutritrack/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
raise exception
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'app.models.NutritionInfo' is mapped, but this instance lacks instrumentation. This occurs when the instance is created before sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(app.models.NutritionInfo) was called.
```

This is my first web-app and I'm having a hard time understanding SQLAlchemy, sorry if this is elementary! Help is much appreciated.

---

I tried to find out when the mapper() function gets called by looking at the docs, but didn't really get anywhere. I thought classes were mapped and instrumented first-thing so I'm a bit confused. I also don't understand what version of SQLAlchemy is using since the SQLalch 2.0.2 docs say this:

Changed in version 2.0: The registry.map_imperatively() method is now used to create classical mappings. The sqlalchemy.orm.mapper() standalone function is effectively removed.

Clarification on these conceptual things would be nice as well :)

Comment: Where and how are you defining and creating your models?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I have an application factory in my `__init__.py` which creates an instance of SQLAlchemy. I then have a `models.py` which imports this instance and uses it to define my models. I'm using Flask-Migrate, a flask wrapper for Alembic, so I'm guessing my models are created when I migrate and upgrade my database, although I'm not sure. Here's the [source code](https://github.com/fg-charles/nutritrack)